# 'docker run -it <container> /usr/bin/bash' yields Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Tags: docker, dockerfile, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.  Using VSCode on a remote machine I created a Dockerfile and devcontainer.json (see below).  I can run this container successfully in VSCode which gives me access to terminal and the ability to run scripts in the container.

After changing some settings I can find the running instance using

```
docker ps
```

I want these settings to be automatic so I commit the running image as follows

```
docker commit 1f7cf26e8f26 container
```

This is where things get confusing.  I can run the following:

```bash
docker run --mount type=bind,source=/home/username/whale/source,target=/workspaces/source \ 
> --mount type=bind,source=/home/username/whale_mount,target=/workspaces/whale_mount \ 
> --mount type=bind,source=/etc/openvpn,target=/etc/openvpn,readonly \
> --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --device /dev/net/tun 
> --name test container \
```

Then, with these commands my script of interest runs fine:

```bash
docker exec -it test1 /bin/bash 
root -> /usr/local/python/current/bin/python /workspaces/source/somescript.py
Script worked!
root -> exit
```

But I want to be able to start the container, run the script, and close the container once it's done with a single line.  So I try this:

```bash
docker run --mount type=bind,source=/home/username/whale/source,target=/workspaces/source \
> --mount type=bind,source=/home/username/whale_mount,target=/workspaces/whale_mount \
>  --mount type=bind,source=/etc/openvpn,target=/etc/openvpn,readonly \
>  --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --device /dev/net/tun \
>  /usr/local/python/current/bin/python /workspaces/source/somescript.py

/usr/local/python/current/bin/python: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong, I've done my best googling and don't see this as a common issue so I assume it's something very silly.  If anyone can offer guidance or pointers I'd appreciate it after dealing with this over the weekend.

Dockerfile and devcontainer.json below:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM  mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:focal
RUN /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/apt-get update && \
    /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/apt-get install -y  && \
    /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/apt-get install -y openvpn
```

devcontainer.json:

```json
{
    "name": "container",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile" //"mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:focal"
    },
     "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/python:1": {
            "version":"3.10.10"
        },
        "ghcr.io/warrenbuckley/codespace-features/sqlite:latest": {
            "autorun":"False"
        }
    },
    "runArgs":["--cap-add","NET_ADMIN",
               "--device","/dev/net/tun",
               //"--mount","type=bind,source=/home/username/whale/source,target=/workspaces/source",
               "--mount","type=bind,source=/home/username/whale_mount,target=/workspaces/whale_mount",
               "--mount","type=bind,source=/etc/openvpn,target=/etc/openvpn,readonly"],//target=/workspaces/openvpn,readonly"],
    "postStartCommand": "/usr/local/python/current/bin/python3.10 -m pip install pandas numpy pexpect"
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] to help understand what's going on.  `docker commit` by its nature is _not_ reproducible, and you shouldn't ever need it.  Without knowing what you did in the container before committing, it's hard to understand what might be wrong here; using a Dockerfile (committed to source control) and exclusively `docker build` to create images is much more maintainable.

Comment: Thank you David! I'll try to encapsulate everything in a single Dockerfile and then build and see if that resolves the issue.

Even if I do nothing but create the container before running `docker commit` it still yields the issue fyi.

Comment: @DavidMaze Moving everything into the Dockerfile and building fixed the issue I was observing.  Thank you.